# Saving Charts with Multiple Series in Excel and PowerPoint

Tags: sql, excel, vba, powerpoint

**Context**

I'm trying to create a multi-series chart/infograph to display total number of sales for the day as compared to the average. The chart consists of three series:

Series 1: The base bar graph showing the number of each item sold

Series 2: A scatterplot to overlay the icons for each item on the appropriate 
bar

Series 3: Another scatterplot to overlay the average number of each of the items sold/day

The data is pulled from a SQL server and is automatically refreshed every 5 minutes using Excel's data connections properties.

I have a display in the office that has a PowerPoint running, showing various office events, etc. that I'd like to add this graph to. Typically I would just copy/paste into a slide in the presentation, maintain links, and call it a day. But therein lies the problem...

**Issue**

When I copy/paste into PowerPoint, only the first series is copied over for some reason. No worries, I thought, I'll just recreate the other two series in PowerPoint directly, linking to the data in Excel. This works until either file is saved/closed. Upon reopening, only the first series remains. For the Excel file, this happens for .xlsx, .xlsm, and .xlsb file types. How can I get charts with multiple series to save properly? Is it more feasible to use code to create the additional series upon opening?

**Photos**

Desired Result:

[image]

After saving/reopening:

[image]

Note: I am using Excel 2016 and PowerPoint 2016. Chart similar to what is described in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g9DK5noi1s&t=710s. Tables for series 2 and 3 are in separate tabs due to how the query pulls into Excel. They are the same structure as the table shown, just different values.

Comment: *When I copy/paste into PowerPoint, only the first series is copied over for some reason* - what are you selecting? Let's try fixing the actual problem rather than patching the symptoms...

Comment: Great question - I'm selecting the entire chart.